# NSAttributedString is hidden/invisible

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I've been scratching my head, why my NSAttributedString has disappeared. I've tried to set `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` attribute to black or any other color. But with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally I remember - I changes the other day the global tintColor of the app to white. So when I changed the tint color of my textField, the brorlem was solved

```
myTextField.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

[image]